# Can I have multi-line column headings for uitables?

Tags: matlab, matlab-uitable

I am using MATLAB Student Version R2011a. I am creating a GUI-table to compare data easier, but I end up in complicated abbreviations, because I don't know how to make multi-line column headings.

I create the table like this (minimal example):

```
myFigure = figure('Position', [100, 200, 400, 100]);

tableData = magic(3);

cnames = {'convPrice/y', 'rechEn', 'priceRechEn'};
     myTable = uitable('Parent', myFigure, ...
     'Data', tableData, ...
     'ColumnName', cnames, ...
     'Position',[10 10 380 80]);
```

I took a screenshot and I will upload it, when I reach reputation 10.
Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create multiline column headings using a vertical slash (|) to separate lines. For example:

```
cnames = {'conv|price', 'rech|en', 'price|rechEn'};
```

Comment: Thats exactly what I was searching for. I was trying around with `\n` and similar versions.